# Type definition not found

Tags: express, types, visual-studio-code, intellisense, jsdoc

I'm starting using VS Code with expressJs. I've decided to split route in different file by using Route.use function.
In the new file I'd like to have intellisense suggesting me all the methods in the app parameters so i've added the `/**@param type {Express} app */` jsdoc. The point is that Intellisense isn't able to find type definitions. What do I have to do to let it find type definition for Express?
Here the code i've wrote:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts"/>

/**@param {Express} app */
module.exports=function(app){
    app.get('/testRoute',function(req,res){
        res.send('Hi, I\'m just a simple test');
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Automatic typings acquisition](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/javascript#_automatic-type-acquisition) should automatically pick up those types for normal `import`
 or `require` statements, so in general you should no longer write `/// reference path=`.

Try something like:

```
import express from 'express';

module.exports = function (/** @type {express.Express} */ app) {
    app.get('/testRoute', function (req, res) {
        res.send('Hi, I\'m just a simple test');
    });
};
```

There's currently a bug when using `require` that prevents types IntelliSense from working properly. [This TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14377) tracks a possible solution